# Is it possible to reuse an 'if' statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, console, code-reuse, reusability

So I am working on a project and I was wondering if it is possible to reuse an 'if' statement. For example, my code right now is

```
import re
import string
userinput=''
print "Hello! What is your name?"

userinput = str(raw_input("My name is "))

if not re.search(r'[A-Za-z]', userinput):
    print "That isn't a name!"
    print str(raw_input("My name is "))
```

and it prints

```
Hello! WHat is your name?
My name is 86124674983@
That isn't a name! 
My name is 986421674941
986421674941
```

As you can see, it recognizes anything other than letters as an invalid entrance, but it only does it once. If you input symbols the second time it prompts you for a name, it takes that random input and prints it. I want it to print

```
Hello! WHat is your name?
My name is 86124674983@
That isn't a name! 
My name is 986421674941
That isn't a name! 
My name is Eli
```

Sorry if this confuses anyone. If you need anything clarified don't hesitate to ask. Thanks very much in advance!!

Comment: If you're totally unfamiliar with the concept of loops (a fundamental structure in almost every programming language), you really should take a look at the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial).

Answer (score 2):

Use a `while` loop:

```
print "Hello! What is your name?"
while True:
    userinput = raw_input("My name is ")
    if not re.search(r'[A-Za-z]', userinput):
        print "That isn't a name!"
    else:
        break

print userinput
```

Note you don't `print` a `raw_input()` - or make it `str` (it already is). All you need is the `raw_input('text')` and it will display `text`.

Comment: no need for the parentheses around the expressions in the print-statements.

Comment: even though there's 'no need' for parentheses around the expressions in the print statement, I think it's good to use them in python 2.x, because when you start working with python 3.x, these little errors might crop up for a bit when you just start :)

Comment: @RussellHickey Which is why I aim to have them, but because i'm using raw_input here... :)

Comment: @Tim I know `raw_input` shows you're using python 2.x, I'm just saying, it is sometimes helpful, to use code that can be used also in 3.x :) If the author of this code decided to change to python 3.x he would need to go through each 2.x file and change the `print "text"`, to code that would have worked regardless :) I know you can use find and replace, but it's just a small time saver if you have multiple files :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a while-loop:

```
print "Hello! What is your name?"
while True:
    userinput = raw_input("My name is ")
    if re.search(r'[A-Za-z]', userinput):
        break
    print "That isn't a name!"
print userinput
```